# Scrollling HorizontalScrollView, want elements to be left aligned

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have a scrolling `HorizontalScrollView` that shows multiple picture, if there is single picture to be displayed, the view is displaying at right end of screen. I want it to be displayed on left side of screen. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

User fill parent and gravity to place elements where you want.

Or you can use RelativeLayout\LinearLayout with left align elements.

Show you XML layout to figure out what exactly you want.

Comment: <com.android.views.HorizontialListView
            android:id="@+id/dealList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white" />

Comment: suppose single picture to be displayed in above horizontal list view,it is being displayed on right end of screen,i want it to be displayed on left side of screen....pls help

Comment: There is not enough information to help, can you pass the whole test project or tell what horizontalListView do you have (i can't find com.android.views.HorizontialListView)